# How to infer variable name in a for-generate block?

Tags: generics, for-loop, vhdl

In an old VHDL design, a component has a generic port:

```
component adc_model is
generic(   RADC_TYPE : adc_type );
port( clk : std_logic;
....
```

And the guy previously did it had named several dozens of constant:

```
constant CH0_RADC_TYPE   : adc_type     :=  I2C_ADC;
constant CH1_RADC_TYPE   : adc_type     :=  deltasigma_ADC;
constant CH2_RADC_TYPE   : adc_type     :=  SPI_ADC;
......
```

so that he can instance multiple unit of the component.

But now I want to do that by using for-generate statement :

```
for i in 0 to 7 generate
    begin
    i_adc_model: adc_model
    generic map(
    RADC_TYPE => CHX_RADC_TYPE(i),
....
```

now I have to do:

```
CHX_RADC_TYPE(00) <= CH0_RADC_TYPE;
CHX_RADC_TYPE(01) <= CH1_RADC_TYPE;
CHX_RADC_TYPE(02) <= CH2_RADC_TYPE;
     .............
```

My question is , is there any smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Not variable - constant. A generic clause declares an interface constant, an interface type, an interface subprogram declaration or an interface package declaration (elements of a generic interface list). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.2 Interface object declarations para 1 "generics", 6.5.3 Interface type declarations para 1,  6.5.4 Interface subprogram declarations para 1 and 6.5.5 Interface package declarations para 1. These describe semantic restrictions not found in the BNF. Older VHDL generics would only be interface constants (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-1993 4.3.2 Interface declarations para 1).

Answer (score 2):

Since the value for the generic port is a constant, then assign the values for the different elements of CHX_RADC_TYPE (assuming array of type `adc_type_array`) when the constant is declared, like:

```
constant CHX_RADC_TYPE : adc_type_array := (0 => CH0_RADC_TYPE,
                                            1 => CH1_RADC_TYPE,
                                            2 => CH2_RADC_TYPE,
                                            ...
```

Comment: (Or the aggregate expression used to specify the values of the elements of the array constant CHX_RADC_TYPE can provide the values previously assigned to each of CH0_RADC_TYPE, CH1_RADC_TYPE, CH2_RADC_TYPE, ... directly, collapsing a level of indirection).